# my app invisible from some devices as galaxy y

Tags: android, android-manifest

i have a problem with my app on the market,my app visible to all devices except GALAXY Y and i am support all screen sizes but i think the problem in manifest permission but i can't determine, and this is my permission code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

please advice me to solve the problem...

Comment: It is not related to your permissions. Unless the Galaxy Y doesn't have a camera.

Comment: What is the minimum `sdk` version requirement? Just search your app in the `play store` from the browser and select your device there. If it says `Incompatible`, then that's the reason why its not showing when you search from your mobile.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"

Comment: but galaxy y has a camera!!

Comment: it doesn't work i delete the camera permission but the problem still exist

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Y has camera of low resolution and so your app might be incompatible with it. Check this : http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-y/514996-some-apps-not-compatible-samsung-galaxy-y.html